# Drools - Accessing fact metadata from within rules

Tags: drools

Within a Drool rule file, how can I access metadata associated with a declared fact?

Roughly speaking I'd like to do the following:

```
declare MyFact
  @myMetaData("foo")
end

rule "MyRule"
when
  exists(OtherFact())
then
  MyFact f = new MyFact();
  global.post(f.metaData["myMetaData"]);
end
```

Really surprised I can't find a simple answer to this, but I may be missing something simple as I've very new to Drools.

I have worked around this by making MyFact extend from a Java class which can programatically retrieve the FactType from the KieBase and then grab the attribute via FactType::getMetaData(), but again, surprised there's not a simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

Much of the chained call shown below can be hidden in a function. You'll have to pass in KieContext kcontext. Or use a static method where the KieBase could be set as a static.

```
package simple;
declare SomeFact
  @Meta1("meta 1")
end

rule showMeta
when
then
   System.out.println( kcontext
                       .getKieRuntime()
                       .getKieBase()
                       .getFactType( "simple", "SomeFact" )
                       .getMetaData()
                       .get( "Meta1" ) );
end
```